# How to initialize 2D surface correctly in PyCUDA? (pycuda._driver.LogicError)

Tags: python, numpy, cuda, pycuda

I'm trying to initialize 2D surface in PyCUDA and fill it with values from NumPy 2D array.The idea, as I get it, is

1. open `drv.ArrayDescriptor`,
2. create `drv.Array` using this descriptor,
3. copy data from NumPy array with `drv.Memcpy2D`,
4. do `set_array` for `SurfaceReference`.

But still I have `pycuda._driver.LogicError` at the last step. A minimal example of what I'm doing:

```
import numpy as np
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule

mod = SourceModule("surface<void, cudaSurfaceType2D> fld_srf;")

def numpy2d_to_array(np_array):
    h, w = np_array.shape
    descr = drv.ArrayDescriptor()
    descr.width = w
    descr.height = h
    descr.format = drv.dtype_to_array_format(np_array.dtype)
    descr.num_channels = 1
    descr.flags = 0
    device_array = drv.Array(descr)
    copy = drv.Memcpy2D()
    copy.set_src_host(np_array)
    copy.set_dst_array(device_array)
    copy.width_in_bytes = copy.src_pitch = np_array.strides[0]
    copy.src_height = copy.height = h
    copy(aligned=True)
    return device_array

fld = np.random.random_integers(-30, 30, (1920, 1080)).astype(np.int32)
srf = mod.get_surfref('fld_srf')
srf_arr = numpy2d_to_array(fld.copy())
srf.set_array(srf_arr)
```

The code above throws following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testsurface.py", line 30, in <module>
    srf.set_array(srf_arr)
pycuda._driver.LogicError: cuSurfRefSetArray failed: invalid value
```

Any ideas how to do this correctly? Or at least why this error appears?

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with the flags: in the 3D case, you have to set
 `descr.flags  = drv.array3d_flags.SURFACE_LDST` 
to allow binding to the surface according to
[this](https://wiki.tiker.net/PyCUDA/Examples/Demo3DSurface).

I don't find the 2D equivalent for pycuda though.